# What's the most effective way to cool down a MBP 13

Tags: macbook-pro, games, temperature, cooling

I have a MacBook Pro 13 retina, which I've just recently started playing Call of Duty on, and I thought if I just blasted my fans the temperature would be kept in check. However, I only checked the actual temp. after playing a bit and it went between 96-100 C (204-212 F). I also have the laptop on raised off of my desk, so theres enough air flow as well. However, the fans don't seem to be enough. Could anyone recommend specific ways or products to cool down my mac?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That’s completely normal operating temperature for graphics intensive processes on your machine. [The System Management Controller](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295) gauges your machine’s temperatures and automatically adjusts the fans accordingly. Furthermore, the SMC will automatically shut your machine down if overheating occurs.

Third party tools (IE, [smcFanControl](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/23049/smcfancontrol)) used to measure temperature and provide users with the ability to manually adjust fan settings **is not recommended at all by Apple**. Here’s an excerpt from Apple Support on [Macbook Operating Temperature](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201640):

> While there are third-party utilities that measure the temperature of a notebook computer, it is important to understand that these utilities are not measuring the external case temperature. The actual case temperature is much lower. Never use third-party applications to diagnose possible hardware issues.

The most important thing to do is ensure the back vent isn’t blocked in anyway to ensure adequate heat dissipation. Additionally, keeping your laptop on a hard surface actually helps ensure proper temperature control.

If you still feel uncomfortable, there’s a [multitude of laptop cooling stations](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/2243862011) available out there which will safely help cool the machine during intensive use.

Comment: Why would you want to know the external case temperature, I'm more worried about the internals, i.e. the cpu. Third-party apps may be just that...third party and not recognized by apple as 100% accurate. However, these apps still use the mac's sensors, it is not as if they make up the numbers. And although I might agree the temperatures I mentioned are within normal operating temperatures, it's not tens of degrees away from overheating, its more like 5 or 6. If you still think this is normal, I'd be willing to agree with you if the temperature spiked that high for only about 10-15 min.

Comment: However, as addicting as games are, I could be playing for like 1 to 2 hours. That I hope you'd agree is not normal, especially if I want my components to last me more than 2-3 years. I realize there a multitude of laptop cooling stations, which is why I tried to phrase my question accordingly, in the hopes that somebody would offer "specific ways or products" to reduce the temperature. I apologize if this rant seems defensive or combative.

Comment: It's just that I knew your type of answer would be the first to come up, I had hoped I had phrased my question just so that this wouldn't happen.Again, nothing personal, I just think running my laptop at a 100 degrees for an hour isn't normal

Comment: @mac_fan_33 When referring to case temperature, Apple isn’t talking about the actual temperature of the aluminum enclosure.  [External Case Temperature](http://www.digikey.com/en/articles/techzone/2011/nov/case-temperature-versus-ambient-temperature) still refers to all the internal components, as opposed to ambient temperatures. The terminology is admittedly misleading, and it would help if Apple clarified in that support article.

Comment: Granted, I though it was referring to the aluminum enclosure. I did some quick reading. I found that intel, has something called the Intel® Power Gadget, it reports Power, Frequency and Temperature. So seeing as the CPU is made by Intel, I think they'd strive to make an accurate tool. Surprisingly enough, the app I use to monitor temperature, at times, actually shows temperatures to be lower than the Intel Power Gadget. Which just goes completely against what Apple claims.